# MySQL optimize comparing function

Tags: mysql, optimization, descriptor

I'm working on an Android program that introduces in a table approximately 15000 integer values(somewhere between 350-500 lines with 32 columns). In the DB I also have other similar values. This 15000 values that I'm talking about represent a processed image, so basically I want to compare the similarity of two images. Now, when I try to compare the values of two images(I'm comparing value by value and count the equal ones), only the data writing process takes about 7 minutes, which is way too long(I want to be able to write and compare at least 5 images in that time). I know that usually you don't work with this kind of things directly in the DB, but do you think that there is anything that I can do, or is it necessary to do this comparison on the server? The values returned by the descriptor came as line elements separated by ',' and each line is separated by ';'. I take each returned element and save it in a tables column. Here is my code:

Split function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `strSplit`(textIn longtext, delim varchar(12), count int) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
declare splitString INT(11);

SET splitString = replace(substring(substring_index(textIn, delim, count), length(substring_index(textIn, delim, count - 1)) + 1), delim, '');

RETURN splitString;
END
```

The function that creates the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myguide`.`objectlocation` (
`ObjectLocationId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ValueObject` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
`DescriptorSize` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`DescriptionObject` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`DataInsert` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`InsertBy` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ObjectLocationId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

And this is the code that does the insert part:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myguide_sp_info_imageId`(descriptorIn longtext, sizeDescriptor INT)
BEGIN

 declare sizeImagesTable INT DEFAULT (select count(*) from objectLocation);
 declare descriptorSizeImage INT;
 declare descriptor INT;
 declare sizeDescriptorImage INT DEFAULT sizeDescriptor;
 declare contorInsertImage INT default 1;
 declare descriptorForSplit longtext;
 declare descriptorImageSaved longtext;
 declare descriptorForSplitImageSaved longtext;

/* check if table exist, drop*/
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS backupObjectLocation;
/* Create temporar table for store info about objectLocation*/
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE backupObjectLocation (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idImage int NOT NULL,
    descriptorSaved longtext not null,
    sizeDescriptorSaved float not null
    );

/* check if table exist, drop*/
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS processImage;
/* Create temporar table for store info about objectLocation*/
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE processImage (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    descriptorSaved varchar(255) ,
    descriptorReceived varchar(255)
    );

SET descriptorImageSaved = RTRIM(descriptorIn);
SET descriptorForSplit = REPLACE(descriptorImageSaved, ';', ',');

INSERT INTO backupObjectLocation (idImage, descriptorSaved, sizeDescriptorSaved)
SELECT ObjectLocationId, ValueObject, DescriptorSize FROM objectLocation;

loop_insertDescriptorImage: LOOP

    if contorInsertImage > sizeDescriptorImage then
        leave loop_insertDescriptorImage;
    end if;

    SET descriptor = strSplit(descriptorForSplit, ',', contorInsertImage);

    INSERT INTO processImage (descriptorReceived) VALUES (descriptor);

    SET contorInsertImage = contorInsertImage + 1;

    ITERATE loop_insertDescriptorImage;
end LOOP;

loop_table: LOOP

    if sizeImagesTable > 1 then
        leave loop_table;
    end if;

    SET descriptorSizeImage = (SELECT sizeDescriptorSaved from backupObjectLocation where id = sizeImagesTable);

    loop_image: LOOP

        if descriptorSizeImage > 1 then
            leave loop_image;
        end if;

        SET descriptorImageSaved = (SELECT descriptorSaved from backupObjectLocation where id = sizeImagesTable);
        SET descriptorForSplitImageSaved = REPLACE(descriptorImageSaved, ';', ',');

        SET descriptorSizeImage = descriptorSizeImage + 1;

        ITERATE loop_image;

    end LOOP;

    SET sizeImagesTable = sizeImagesTable + 1;

    ITERATE loop_table;
end LOOP;

select descriptorImageSaved;
select * from backupObjectLocation;
select * from processImage;
END
```

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Without (at minimum!) your query, explain plan and table structure with indexes there is nothing we can do to help you. It would all be guessing.

Comment: Do add the table structure and part of code which does matching, it would help to answer.

Comment: As far as I know, you should not do that in DB. you should compare them multithreaded and  parallel.

Comment: This is an image-processing question, not a database question.  You must load the entire data in RAM and work on it there.